# There is metal behind the drywall above my kitchen sink - is it safe to drill where there ISNT metal?

Tags: drywall, mounting

I am trying to mount a magnetic knife rack to the wall above my kitchen sink. I have a stud finder that is showing me there are some thick tubes/plates/columns of metal behind the drywall. Based on most of the advice here, it seems like I should NOT try to drill into it. However, there does seem to be space inbetween the metal where it is just drywall. If I am careful, can I just drill into these parts of the wall instead?

Thank you!

Comment: I would be careful.  If they used protection plates, then the wires/pipes will be closer to the back of the drywall.  A drill bit will go though wire/pipe as easy as a screw/nail.  Is the finder only showing/finding a few inches of metal or feet?  You might have metal studs instead of wood.

Comment: The finder is finding a few sections of metal, yes. The finder is indicating that the metal is about 3-3.5 inches wide.  there is more metal than non-metal in the section of wall above my kitchen sink. normally studs are only 1.5 right?  what would this size indicate?

Comment: If the pipes/wires are going though blocking(vertical) instead of studs(horizontal), it would be about the right size, or there are double studs.  Too many ways of placing pipes/wires to be sure.

Comment: so you don't think it's safe to drill in that are at all then? i dont know where else to mount a knife block then lol

Comment: For knifes I would usually prefer a solid mounting with screws, you do not want sharp knifes falling on you.  If the knife block is small enough(weight of the knifes plus block), gluing to the wall might be an option.  I do not know your house, electric/plumbing plans, your stud finder is saying something is there.  If it is safe or not is very hard to say.

Comment: Have you considered a good two sided tape?

Comment: 3M has some pretty serious two-sided tapes, including some which are rubbery or foamed so they make good contact despite surface irregularities. Depends on how much weight you're trying to support, of course.